# Community poll from right to left

Tags: magento-1.9

Basically I need to change the position of my community poll from the right side of the webpage to the left and I don't know how to do it

Comment: Here's a hint.  You will need to "unset" the block from where it currently is, then "insert" it where you want it to be in layout xml.  This should help you on the right path: https://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/magento-tutorials/xml-blocks-local-xml/

Answer (score 0):

**Via File**

Kindly choose the page layout 2 column left, go to that page xml layout, add corresponding xml code for community poll, After clear cache you get the result.

**Via Backend**

Go to magento backend -> cms -> pages ->select existing page/ create new page with 2 column left -> add community poll xml code in design tab.